# Почему не сравнивы 2 множества?

Tags: математика, множества

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: пример]

Как это вообще работает?.
отношение частичного порядка - это отношение которое рефлексивно, семметрично, и транзитивно,
здесь <= - єто я так понял обозначение частичное упорядочение,

с определения следует что 2 элемента a и b частично упорядоченного множества (S, <=)сравнимы если a <= b или b <= a

А цепь если каждые два элемента частично упорядоченного множества (S, <=) сравнимые.

ну а с фото примера 2.50?.
получим {a,b} <= ∅ или  ∅ <= {a,b} - они типо сравнимы или что?.  а множества {a,b} <= {b,c} или  {b,c} <= {a,b} не сравнимы?

Comment: Если бы вы еще показали отношение частичного порядка из примера 2.45, было бы проще говорить о чем-то...

Comment: Harry, добавил пример

Comment: На будущее - пишите не `Harry`, а `@Harry` - ну, или кому вы там пишете - так будет оповещение об ответе. А так - вы же понимаете, что просто каждые 10 минут смотреть, а не ответил ли кто - никто не будет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере 2.45 отношение частичного порядка задается как "множество `X` является подможеством множества `Y`". И тогда говорим, что `X` сравнимо с `Y`.

По-этому, да - `{a,b}` и `∅` сравнимы, так как пустое множество является подмножеством множества `{a,b}`.

Для пары же множеств `{a,b}` и `{b,c}`, ни одно из них не является подмножеством другого. А значит они несравнимы.

В этом примере еще может сбивать с толку использование символа `≤`, так как для чисел это отношение *полного порядка*, т.е. для любых двух чисел `a` и `b` либо `a≤b` либо `b≤a`. Но в литературе именно этот символ используется для обозначения частичного порядка.

Хочу ответить на вопросы из комментариев о способах задания или определения отношений. Отношение это всегда множество пар. Но задать это множество можно по разному.

Первый способ, это просто перечислить все элементы множества `R` (т.е. все пары `(A, B)`, которые входят в `R`). У этого способа сразу два неудобства:

1. очень долго записывать
2. посмотрев на элементы из `R` непросто сообразить, а какое правило это отношение задает

Второй способ, это задать правило, которое описывает отношение в общем виде. Вот как в примере `R = {(T, V) для T ∈ X, V ∈ X и T ⊆ V}`. Обратите внимание, что тут мы задали (или по другому сказать определили) точно то же отношение.

Третий способ, это сказать словами `R - это бинарное отношение "является подмножеством" над множеством X`. И опять же, этим определением, мы задаем точно то же отношение.

Все три способа, это просто разные способы задать некое множество пар.

И все следующие высказывания эквивалентны:

1. `({1}, {1, 2}) ∈ R`
2. `{1}` является подмножеством `{1, 2}`
3. `{1} ≤ {1, 2}`

И да, если элементы принадлежат отношению порядка (или по другому находятся в отношении порядка), то они "сравнимы". Т.е. смысл такой, что мы можем их сравнить между собой. Отношения порядка задает, собственно, порядок для элементов, которые входят в отношение, т.е. возможность сказать какой из них больше или меньше. И именно в этом смысле используется термин "сравнимы", их можно сравнить между собой.

Comment: окей, если <= - Отношение частичного порядка, тогда если просто для 2 элементов a,b то либо a <= b или b <= a.       а вот если мы говорим не про элементы а множества A и B то они сравнимы с отношением частичного порядка "<=" если A являеться подмножеством B. так работает это сравнение?

Comment: ну тоесть отношение частичного порядка (<=) указывает на дополнительный параметр (условие), например: "<=" = A есть подмножеством B, или  y больше чем x,    И если какието элементы, множества попали под это условие и оно истинно то эти элементы/множества сравнимы?

Comment: Добавил еще пояснений.